# Excel VBA 解像度を上げたPCでフォームなどを作ると、実行時にフォームが小さくなる解決法

Tags: vba, excel

Excel2016にて、初めに画面解像度を150%にしたPCでExcelを立ち上げ、フォームでいろいろ
作っていたのですが、ほかの解像度が100%のPCで動かそうとすると、**異様**にフォームが小さくなって表示されてしまいます。

また、もとの150%の解像度のPCで編集しようとVBEでそのフォームを確認すると、やはり小さくなってしまっています。

しかし、少しでもマウスで編集中のフォームサイズを調整しようとすると、**途端に**もとの大きさに戻ります。

この解決方法を教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になりそうです。[Office ソリューションでの高 DPI と DPI スケーリングの処理](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/client-developer/ddpi/handle-high-dpi-and-dpi-scaling-in-your-office-solution), [DPI制御の問題](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~ef2o-inue/vbnet/sub13_09_030.html), [ユーザーフォームを解像度に合わせてサイズ調整](https://vbanobuhinko.com/%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%82%92%E8%A7%A3%E5%83%8F%E5%BA%A6%E3%81%AB%E5%90%88%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9B%E3%81%A6%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E8%AA%BF%E6%95%B4/), [列幅・行高をDPI取得しピクセルで指定する](https://excel-ubara.com/excelvba4/EXCEL_VBA_437.html)

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。無事解決できました。しかし、なんかそもそもこういう事象が発生すること自体、なんか釈然としません。これは不具合とは違うのでしょうかね。